# How can I push_back data in a 2d vector of type int

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I have a vector and want to store int data in to it at run time can I store the data in a 2D vector in this manner ?

```
std::vector<std::vector <int>> normal:
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            normal[i].push_back(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a "2d vector", you have a vector *of vectors* of `int`. If you remember that it's easy to see what you need to do: Push back a vector for each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: or if size is known at declaration time you could pass it to the constructor or call resize

Comment: Thank you for explaining it i was little bit confused about it

Answer (score 27):

Yes, but you also need to push each of the sub-vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> normal;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    normal.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
    {    
        normal[i].push_back(j);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You are manipulating a vector of vectors.
As such, when declaring `normal` it is empty and does not contain any element.

You can either :

#### Resize the vector prior to inserting elements

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > normal;
normal.resize(20);

for (size_t i = 0; i < normal.size(); ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
        normal[i].push_back(j);
}
```

This may be slightly more efficient than pushing an empty vector at each step as proposed in other answers.

#### Use a flat 2D array

If you want to store a 2D array, this is not the optimal solution, because :

1. Your array data is spread across N different dynamically allocated buffers (for N lines)
2. Your array can have a different number of columns per line (because nothing enforces that `normal[i].size() == normal[j].size()`

Instead, you can use a vector of size `N * M` (where `N` is the number of lines and `M` the number of columns), and access an element at line `i` and columns `j` using the index `i + j * N` :

```
size_t N = 20;
size_t M = 20;
std::vector<int> normal;
normal.resize(N * M);

for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        normal[i + j * N] = j;
```

Comment: I think you mean to say `normal.resize(10)` which represents column length

Answer (score 3):

create a temporary vector push elements into this temporary vector and then push this temporary vector(v2 in my code) into a 2d vector(v1 in my code).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<algorithm>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

    vector<vector<int>> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    v2.push_back(1);
    v2.push_back(2);
    v2.push_back(13);
    v2.push_back(14);
    v2.push_back(15);

    v1.push_back(v2);
    //i pushed v2 into v1

    int j=0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++)
    {
        cout<<v1[0][i]<<"\t";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly assign to `[i]` without allocating the outer and inner vectors first. One solution to this would be to create the inner vectors inside your for loop, then once those are populated, push_back to the outer vector.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> normal;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    std::vector<int> temp;
    for(j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        temp.push_back(j);
    }
    normal.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a vector of vectors.

normal[i] Does not exist because you have not created it.

```
std::vector<std::vector <int> > normal:
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    normal.emplace_back();
    for(j=0;j<20;j++){
        normal.back().push_back(j);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(j=0;j<20;j++){
        std::cout << normal[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector <int> > normal;
    normal.resize( 10, std::vector<int>( 20 ) );

    for ( auto &v : normal ) std::iota( v.begin(), v.end(), 0 );

    for ( const auto &v : normal )
    {
        for ( int x : v ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

You can write a corresponding function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

template <typename T>
T & init_2d( T &container, size_t m, size_t n )
{
    container.resize( m, typename T::value_type( n ) );

    for ( auto &item : container ) std::iota( item.begin(), item.end(), 0 );

    return container;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;

    for ( const auto &v : init_2d( v, 10, 20 ) )
    {
        for ( int x : v ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate n empty vectors, that is, empty vector for each index. Then push_back() can be applied.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> normal;
    normal.resize(n);   //Allocating 'n' empty vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
             normal[i].push_back(j);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please state on the answer what is the main difference between your answer and others people?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to use such pointer to the sub vectors. But it still need to be declared with an empty vector before we can push_back() the sub vector.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

int main () {
    vector<vector<ll>> normal;
    for (ll i=0; i<10; i++) {
        normal.push_back({}); //init empty sub vector
        for (ll j=0; j<20; j++) {
            vector<ll>& temp = normal[i]; //point the sub vector
            temp.push_back(j);            //pus_back the sub vector
        }
    }
    for (ll i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (ll j=0; j<20; j++) {
            printf("%lld ", normal[i][j]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand with a simple greedy problem.
Stock buy and sell:

One approach is using temporary vector i.e.

```
vector<vector<int> > stockBuySell(vector<int> A, int n){
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    vector<int> temp;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(A[i]>A[i-1])
        {
            temp.push_back(i-1);
            temp.push_back(i);
            v.push_back(temp);
            temp.clear();
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Another approach is :

```
vector<vector<int> > stockBuySell(vector<int> A, int n){
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(A[i]>A[i-1])
        v.push_back({i-1,i});
    }
    return v;
}
```

So, If we have to push some small size vectors like 2 or 3 in 2-d vector then this way we can directly push in a 2-d vector i.e. vector_name.push_back({1,2,3}); likewise using {} brackets. Hence we don't have to use any extra temporary vector.